# Unique User for all visitor, but possibility to comment with unique name

Tags: comments, username

Maybe a little bit more information: 
The website is a local blog for a company. They generate only one user and password each 3 month. This username is used for all people who work in this company. They all have the same account.

My goal is that they can add comment entering a new nickname instead of the account username. So they can answer to each other with other name than the same username.

Sorry my english is very poor.

Here is an image of my goal:

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWSpj.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "they all will have the same username for the comment." - what do you mean exactly? That each comment will appear to be from the same user? Can you provide an example or screenshot of this?

Comment: Why doesn't each user each have a separate account? I imagine the problem when some user changes the password. You could e.g. open up for registration to change this setup.

Comment: It's for security reason ( the client wants this ) and they can't change the password, I hided this.